# How to extract meta description from urls using python?

Tags: python, url, extract, meta-tags, goose

I want to extract the title and description from the following website:

view-source:http://www.virginaustralia.com/au/en/bookings/flights/make-a-booking/

with the following snippet of source code:

```
<title>Book a Virgin Australia Flight | Virgin Australia
</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="Search for and book Virgin Australia and partner flights to Australian and international destinations." />
```

I want the title and meta content.

I used goose but it does not do a good job extracting. Here is my code:

```
website_title = [g.extract(url).title for url in clean_url_data]
```

and

```
website_meta_description=[g.extract(urlw).meta_description for urlw in clean_url_data]
```

The result is empty

Comment: What about BeautifulSoup? - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please check [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc) as solution.

For question above, you may use the following code to extract "description" info:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.virginaustralia.com/au/en/bookings/flights/make-a-booking/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

metas = soup.find_all('meta')

print [ meta.attrs['content'] for meta in metas if 'name' in meta.attrs and meta.attrs['name'] == 'description' ]
```

output:

```
['Search for and book Virgin Australia and partner flights to Australian and international destinations.']
```

Comment: You may want to add the check for content to exist in meta.attrs, as malformed html can cause exceptions to be thrown otherwise:
`[ meta.attrs['content'] for meta in metas if 'name' in meta.attrs and 'content' in meta.attrs and meta.attrs['name'] == 'description' ]`

Comment: you may want to add () to print statement )

Answer (score 1):

do you know html xpath?
use lxml lib with xpath to extract html element is one fast way.

```
import lxml

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html_content)
title_element = doc.xpath("//title")
website_title = title_element[0].text_content().strip()
meta_description_element = doc.xpath("//meta[@property='description']")
website_meta_description = meta_description_element[0].text_content().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

import metadata_parser

page = metadata_parser.MetadataParser(url='www.xyz.com')
metaDesc=page.metadata['og']['description']
print(metaDesc)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup to achieve this.

Should be helpful -

```
metas = soup.find_all('meta') #Get Meta Description
for m in metas:
    if m.get ('name') == 'description':
        desc = m.get('content')
        print(desc)
```